# Multi index or groupby with related dataframe data

Tags: python, pandas

The following image shows a multi index and I am trying to do something similar with my data:

[image: mutiindex]

In order to demonstrate what I am trying to do with my real data I have put together this simplified dummy data to reproduce it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
cols = list(df.columns)
colsComb = list(combinations(cols, 2))
colsComb
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
#create new columns with pairs of 
newcols = []
for row in colsComb:
    a,b = row
    name = str(a+ '/' + b)
    df[name] = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index,)
    df[name] = abs(df[a] - df[b])
    newcols.append(name)
```

So, as my `A/B` data is derived from `A` and `B` I would like another way to recall `A` and `B` via an `A/B` related index/groupby or similar as per the way `one` and `two` can be called by `bar` in the first example above.

I have put this example together and hope that there may be some obvious ways to do this that I am missing as I am struggling with this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't grasp what exactly do you want. If you just want to add a multi-index, as in your example you can do this

```
In [1]: newlevel = ['bar', 'bar', 'foo']
        df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([newlevel, df.columns])

In [2]: print df.T      
                   0         1         2         3         4     ...
        bar A -0.137985 -1.163524  0.276460 -0.417816 -0.353671  ... 
            B -0.365237 -1.204439  0.062629 -0.779051 -1.177906  ...  
        foo C  0.085098 -1.357175  0.825194  1.211555  0.027403  ...
```